# DOM manipulations in Python (if some element contains only one other element...)

Tags: python, dom

I need to remove all `<p>`s where they are of no need. Such as convert `<div><p>xxxx</p></div>` to `<div>xxxx</div>`.

How can I do it with DOM? "If `<div>` has only one `<p>` inside, than assign that `<p>`'s text to `<div>` and remove this `<p>`".

I'd rether do it with **regex**, but some people say that it is bad. I can't imagine how it is done with DOM.

```
text = "<div><p>xxxx</p></div>"
???
```

Is it possible to solve with DOM at all? Or good old regex is better for this case?
Python, not JavaScript.

Comment: I don't have time right now, but I think it is quite possible for what I have been doing with xml.dom.minidom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

text = "<div><p>xxxx</p></div>"
doc = minidom.parseString(text)

# For each div in the root document
for tag in doc.childNodes:
    # If it's a <p> and there's only one
    if len(tag.childNodes) == 1 and tag.childNodes[0].tagName == 'p':
        # p_node = <p>xxx</p>
        p_node = tag.childNodes[0]
        # p_text_node = xxx
        p_text_node = p_node.childNodes[0]
        value = p_node.nodeValue
        # Delete the <p>xxx</p>
        p_node.parentNode.removeChild(p_node)
        # Set the <div></div> -> <div>xxx</div>
        tag.appendChild(p_text_node)

print doc.toxml()
```

and yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><div>xxxx</div>
```

I hope you'll accept the answer I gave for your other question too since I put in all the work for you ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way you can do it using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> somehtml = '<html><title>hey</title><body><p>blah</p><div><p>something</p></div></body></html>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(somehtml)
>>> for p in soup.findAll('p'):
...    if p.parent.string is None and len(p.parent.contents) == 1:
...       p.parent.string = p.string
...       p.extract()
>>> soup
<html><title>hey</title><body><p>blah</p><div>something</div></body></html>
```

This searches for all `<p>` elements that have a parent with no content and only one child (the `<p>` element), then copies the contents of the `<p>` element to the parent and removes the `<p>` element.

Comment: can we update the HTML content (like DOM manipulation) using bs4?

Answer (score -1):

Building upon @jterrace answer:

(PLEASE EDIT THIS QUESTION SO THAT IT IS COMPLETE, OR COMMENT)

I think the way to go is to create a `minidom.Document` so that you can modify its xml nodes.

```
#coding: utf-8

from xml.dom import minidom

text = "<div><p>xxxx</p></div>"

dom = minidom.parseString(text)

for p in dom.getElementsByTagName('p'):
    print p.childNodes
    # and what now?
```

Answer (score -5):

If you have jquery, this will work.

```
$('div').each(function() {

    if ($(this).children().length > 1)
        return

    if ($(this).children()[0].tagName != "P")
        return

    this.innerHTML = $(this).children()[0].innerHTML;
});
```